# Please describe this JavaScript functional representation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, transpose, array-algorithms

https://leetcode.com/problems/transpose-matrix/discuss/147063/JS-one-line-solution

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} A
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var transpose = function(A) {
    return A[0].map((val, ind) => A.map(row => row[ind]));
};
```

I can hardly understand part `A[0].map((val, ind) => A.map(row => row[ind]))`.

I think `A[0].map((val, ind)` is the purpose of extracting the index.

But I do not know about `=> A.map(row => row[ind])`. Map methods and arrow functions are intertwined, making it difficult to understand.

Could you explain it to me in an easy to understand way?

Answer (score 1):

`map` method is used to create new array of calling a specific function for each value of input Array.

your function is equivalant to

```
var transpose = function(A) {
    return A[0].map(function(val, ind){
        return A.map(function(row){
            return row[ind];
        });
    } );
};
```

or only in function form

```
var transpose = function(A) {
    var outerArr = [];
    A[0].forEach(function(val,ind){
        var innerArr = [];
        A.forEach(function(row){
            innerArr.push(row[ind]);
        });
        outerArr.push(innerArr);
    })
    return outerArr;
};
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.